# How do I make a pull request for only one specific commit in Mercurial?

Tags: version-control, mercurial, fork, bitbucket, pull

I have forked a Mercurial repository hosted on Bitbucket. I don't have write permissions for the original repository. I made several commits to my fork. Let's call them A, B, C and D, i.e. latest first:

- D *[latest]*
- C
- B <--- Pull only changes made in this commit
- A *[oldest]*

Now I want to make pull request for all the changes in commit B exclusively, ignoring A, C and D. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

First of all let's understand how your graph looks like. Let's suppose the tip of your forked repo is `x` and it has linear history with no branching. So your history looks like this:

```
[1000's of commits] -> parent(parent(x)) -> parent(x) -> x
```

Now you made four commits namely `A`, `B`, `C` and `D` with `A` being the oldest one and `D` being the latest one. Now you graph looks something like this:

```
x -> A -> B -> C -> D
```

Note the history earlier than `x` is still intact, its not included above because its not required piece of information for what we are discussing.

Now you want to create a pull request containing only `B` changeset. That's not possible with current state because the main repo does not knows about `A` also which is parent of `B`. You can't have a child until it's parent/s is/are not there.

So if we want to just make a pull request of `B` changeset we need to `rebase` it on `x`.

`rebase` is an extension in Mercurial and you can turn it on by adding the following lines to your `.hg/hgrc`

```
[extensions]
rebase =
```

Let's rebase once we have extension enabled.

```
hg rebase -s B -d x
```

This will result in:

```
x -> A
   \-> B -> C -> D
```

Now you can create a pull request because `B`'s parent is `x`. You can also have more cleaner state of history by rebasing `C` to again `A`. It will result in two branches, one containing the changesets you want to push, other local changesets. Rebasing again looks like:

```
hg rebase -s C -d A
```

And the resulting state of history is:

```
x -> A -> C -> D
   \-> B
```

You can now easily create a pull request containing only `B` changeset.

**Related Link:**

[Rebase Extension](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/RebaseExtension)